# Android, When the screen orientation changes, the app freezes

Tags: android, orientation

When the screen orientation in the app changes, the app freezes. There are xml files for both portrait and landscape mode. So the UI adjusts when orientation changes but the app freezes.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: is it working fine after some time (after few minutes)....?

Comment: @Noby, it doesn't work..
As what I came to know is that I have to re initialize the view elements once i call  setContentView(R.layout.main); 
Then it worked fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By freezes if you mean listner and other handler not working , this is because  after setContentView(R.layout.main) you have rto einitialize views like

```
button btn = findViewById();
btn.setOnClickListener();
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove setContentView(R.layout.main) from `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` method if you already have it in `onCreate(Bundle)` method.

It seems that you call setContentView(R.layout.main) twice.

Answer (score 0):

the default way to handle reorientation in Android is destroying and creating the activity again. It's possible that you have a slow process in the onCreate? if so, you must save the values processed in a the onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and recover the information when onCreate as exlain google [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges).